# Loading an image dynamically works only in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
image = document.createElement("image");
image.src ="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png";
e = document.getElementById('id');
$(image).load(function() {
    $(image).hide();
    e.appendChild(image);
    $(image).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

What makes this code to run only in Chrome?
http://jsfiddle.net/QLFf3/1/

Comment: For readability and maintainability, you should not mix JavaScript and jQuery like this. You can directly use jQuery, e.g. `$('<img />').load(...).attr('src', '...').appendTo('#id');`.

Comment: @FelixKling I have read somewhere an article that $('<img />').load -kind of load is much slower

Comment: Well, it will be slower because you are going through jQuery, but I doubt that it will have any impact on your application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create an "img" element. There is no native element called "image"

*Edit*
Since it appears you are using jQuery, you can just do this:

```
$('<img/>')
    .attr('src', 'http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png')
    .css({display:'none'})
    .appendTo('body')
    .load(function(){
        $(this).fadeIn(1000);
    });
```

Of course, the .appendTo() bit needs to target whatever place in DOM you are aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
image = new Image();
```

instead of

```
image = document.createElement("image");
```

see http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/775889-document-createelement-img-vs-new-image

Comment: I decided to do this width jquery because its easier and more comfortable - what works width jq it will work in every browser

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sendmetamil/QLFf3/5/) out.

Try, `image = new Image();`

Comment: Why mix native methods with jQuery? If you're going to do it, do it one way or the other.

Comment: @Geuis: Your answer is the correct solution for this problem. I answered before seeing ur answer.